# How create follows mouse movement - javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, background

I'm a beginner at coding.
I want to do effec like on this page - http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds

I use scripts from this site and GreenSock GSAP animation library. But I can't connect this with my site. This is my html:

```
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="demo-canvas" width="1400" height="622"></canvas>
  </div>
```

and part of javascript where I use Id elements:

```
largeHeader = document.getElementById('container');
    largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

    canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

When I use this javascript code, then I get this error "TypeError: largeHeader is null".

How correctly use this effect ?

Comment: Is your code either a) at the end of the body element, or b) wrapped in a DOM ready handler? Otherwise you are referencing the DOM element before it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Is your code either

- a) at the end of the `<body>` element, or
- b) wrapped in a DOM ready handler?

Otherwise you are referencing the DOM element before it exists.

This is one way to wrap it for DOM ready (shortcut handler with locally scoped `$`):

```
jQuery(function($){
    var largeHeader = document.getElementById('container');
    largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

    var canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
});
```

Notes:

- The traditional DOM ready handler is `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE });` but the shortcut is nicer
- Also use `var` to declare local variables. otherwise they pollute the global scope.